# Appcenter - Test on emulator

Tags: visual-studio-app-center-test

Trying to add appcenter CLI commands for example: **appcenter test run espresso --app "Test-apps" --devices "google-pixel-2-android-10" --app-path pathToFile.apk --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir pathToEspressoBuildFolder**

But where should add this CLI command & how to add it stepwise. Can anyone explain clearly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not very clear, it would be great if you copy and paste the errors you are getting, share a screenshot or give more details. Tell us what OS you are using, where did you get this command from?

You need to open the terminal or shell, and paste the commands in there.

There are a few pre-requisites though, the documentation is not super beginner friendly.

**From the docs:**

1. Install NodeJS https://nodejs.org/en/
2. In the terminal, run `npm install -g appcenter-cli`

Comment: I was able to run appcenter CLI but however not sure how it can plugged in pipeline. I mean how this CLI command should be foradded in yaml file

Comment: You definitely need to provide more details. What pipeline system are you using, and what are you actually trying to do?